# MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC

Tags: php, mysql

Конкретный вопрос. Данная функция нормально воспринимает перенос каретки, есть какие-нибудь особенности?

Comment: Вопрос непонятен!

Comment: @Святослав, ну так проверьте сами: воспринимает ли? Что за глупые вопросы !?

Comment: А что можно ещё использовать помимо mysql_fetch_assoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот [nl2br()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) ответ на вопрос

Answer (score 0):

что вы подразумеваете под

> воспринимает **Enter**

Перенос каретки?

Comment: Да. Если пишешь текст с переносами, то он записывается нормально в бд, а при выводе ничего нет. В чём проблема? Если без переноса, то всё нормально.